# filter results based on smalldatetime comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have my database date stored in smalldatetime.
now, if i need to filter the results based on(say today's date equals the date in database), what is the best way to do it?

```
select * from tbl Emp where Emp.date = cast(getdate() as smalldatetime)
```

//this will not match the date

the other way i found but not sure if casting the date in table affects performance like:

```
select * from tbl Emp where cast(Emp.date as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: Do you have an index on Emp.date?

Comment: yes, i think i do have index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is accurate:

```
where cast(Emp.date as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

This method is accurate and can use an index:

```
where (Emp.date >= cast(getdate() as date) and
       Emp.date < cast(getdate() + 1 as date))
```

The `+ 1` is a convenience in SQL Server that adds one day to a `datetime` value.  But, you can also use

```
where (Emp.date >= cast(getdate() as date) and
       Emp.date < dateadd(day, 1, cast(getdate() as date))
      )
```

Comment: thanks Gordon i think i'll use the 2nd option. it seems to work.

Comment: Just a sidenote [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: @wewesthemenace . . . I have great admiration for Aaron Bertrand.  Sometimes, though, `+ 1` is sometimes just easier to write than the full `dateadd()` -- and it is compatible with more databases.  Oh, why oh why are all databases different on date arithmetic.  By the way, you can add to the reasons not to use it that `+ 1` does not work on `date` -- that would be my number one reason.  I'm surprised Aaron's blog doesn't mention that.